# « Marcher sur/suivre les pas/traces de quelqu'un » au figuré pour « imiter, suivre l'exemple » : pas et traces ?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, locutions, lexique

> Plusieurs ONG ont appelé la France, qui refuse jusqu'ici de suspendre
>   ses contrats avec Riyad, à **suivre les pas** de Londres.
>   ([Lapresse.ca](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/201906/20/01-5231011-defiant-trump-le-senat-americain-bloque-une-vente-darmes-a-riyad.php))

Au TLFi on trouve « [suivre](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suivre) les pas, le sillage, les traces de qqn. » mais c'est un sens concret rattaché à une *voie terrestre*. On trouve aussi « marcher dans les [pas](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pas/1) de quelqu'un », toujours un sens concret. À [*trace*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trace/0) on a « marcher sur/suivre les traces de quelqu'un » pour le sens au figuré *imiter, suivre l'exemple de quelqu'un*. On a un peu le même scénario au Larousse en ligne ([trace](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/trace/78844/locution?q=suivre#176125)) mais on a aussi « marcher sur les [pas](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pas/58420?q=pas#58070) de quelqu'un » pour ce sens au figuré ; idem au [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/marcher_sur_les_pas_de) où on le qualifie par ailleurs d'emploi *familier*. De plus, le Wiktionnaire réunit plusieurs termes dans une extension de sens au figuré de [*suivre*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/suivre) pour « aller, continuer d’aller dans une même direction » dont *pas, traces, chemin et fil*.

Vu que le TLFi n'est plus mis à jour depuis 1994, on se demande s'il y a vraiment asymétrie selon le verbe et le terme ou si l'usage a évolué et va dans le sens d'un emploi figuré uniforme pour *marcher/suivre* avec *pas/traces*. Ou les différences relèvent-elles uniquement de la présentation des emplois au figuré dans les dictionnaires consultés ? Personnellement je trouve *suivre les traces* plus usuel qu'avec *pas* et je ne semble pas connaître l'aspect « négatif » (aveuglément, docilement) d'*[emboîter](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/embo%C3%AEter) le pas* au figuré que j'aurais bien vu apparaître dans l'exemple plutôt que *suivre* (et donc pour moi c'est avec *emboîter* semble-t-il que le sens au figuré de *suivre les traces* de quelqu'un se réalise avec les *pas*).

- Peut-on statuer sur l'emploi au figuré de *marcher/suivre* avec les
  *traces/pas* : y a-t-il une parfaite équivalence, l'emploi avec *traces* précède-t-il celui avec *pas* ; y a-t-il des nuances
  de sens, s'agit-il de variantes régionales de l'emploi ?
- Incidemment, peut-on confirmer qu'il y a systématiquement cet aspect
  négatif à *emboîter le pas* (docilement, aveuglément, quasiment se
  plier au joug) ?

Comment: Il ne me semble pas qu'il y ait une différence entre l'emploie des deux expressions. Sinon non ce n'est pas toujours négatif, cela va dépendre du contexte et de la personne suivit. Par exemple si un religieux marche dans les pas d'un saint ou d'une divinité cela ne va pas être négatif.

Comment: Personnellement, je ne trouve pas qu'il y ait d'aspect négatif à *emboîter le pas* ; la seule vraie différence comparé à *suivre les traces/pas* serait qu'*emboîter* implique une action presque immédiate, on fait la même chose dans la foulée. *Suivre les pas* peut se faire sur une période très longue (un enfant qui fait les même études que son père, un pélerin qui effectue son chemin de croix, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de nuances, ni de variations régionales, dans l'emploi de toutes ces formules. Elles sont équivalentes, à l'exception de *emboiter le pas* qui implique une proximité, une immédiateté. C'est cette nuance qui permet de l'utiliser de façon péjorative en suggérant, suivant les contextes, un empressement servile, une absence de réflexion propre, un manque d'autonomie. Cela reste optionnel et dépendant du contexte, *emboiter le pas* peut également prendre une valeur tout à fait neutre.

Quelques recherches sur Google Ngram Viewer indiquent que, bien que les expressions avec traces ont toujours été plus fréquentes que celles avec pas, les deux variantes remontent à la première moitié du XVIème siècle.

Comment: Qu'entends-tu par "l'une apparait avant l'autre" ?

Comment: Quelques recherches sur Google Ngram Viewer indiquent que, bien que les expressions avec *traces* ont toujours été plus fréquentes que celles avec *pas*, les deux variantes remontent au milieu du XIVème siècle.